# How to design flutter app layout for tab and phone

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layoutbuilder

I am new to flutter development and I am trying to build app for both tab and phone layout. There are lot of article online which uses either media query or Layout builder but in both the cases they are checking the break point as `width > 600`. This fails when my device is landscape orientation and even thought it's a phone tab layout is shown on screen.

This does not work for my device and won't work on most of flagship device because they are higher resolution. I tried increasing the check `width > 800` which works for my device but I am not sure it will work for all the devices.

Is there any better way of achieving this ?

Comment: Can you make the sizes and paddings of/between widgets proportional to the size of the device?

Comment: The padding are already proportional to screen size.

Comment: maybe you can disable orientation `landscape` for mobile device  if your UI not required landscape orientation on mobile device